# Unity3D - Destroying a particle system's emitter so that lingering particles persist

Tags: unity-game-engine, particle-system

I am instantiating a particle system like this:
`atkP = Instantiate(attackparticles,transform.position, Quaternion.identity);`

And then destroying it like this:
`Destroy(atkP);`

The particle system is set on loop because I do not want to specify a duration. (Particles will be emitted for variable lengths).

My problem is, since `atkP` is an entire particle system, any lingering particles are also destroyed. I would like to just destroy the emitter so that the lingering particles appear to organically resolve themselves. I checked out the docs and saw that the ParticleEmitter class is obsolete, so I can't really go `atkP.GetComponent<ParticleEmitter>()` or anything like that.

Comment: You need to tell the emitter to stop emitting new particles.

Answer (score 0):

Try to stop emitting particles and then use Destroy(variableLengthOfAParticle).

You should really use ParticleSystem instead of ParticleEmitter.